# Formula for the first base-$n$ digit of $n^{d+1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^d$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $k,n,d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>1$.

Converting $k$ in a base $n$,

$$k = (n_{ l} ~\cdots~ n_2~ n_1)_{n} \quad\text{where}\quad n_{l} \ne 0$$

> Show that, if
>   $$k = n^{d+1} - \sum_{i=1}^n i^d$$ then
>   $$
> n_l=n - \left\lceil\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d}\right\rceil
> $$

**Example**

Let $n=3$ and $d=2$.

$$3^3-(1^2+2^2+3^2)= 13 = (111)_{3}$$

So $n_l = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture doesn't always hold based on the stated conditions. For example, $n = 2, d = 3$ results in

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^d = \sum_{i=1}^{2}i^3 = 1 + 2^3 = 9 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$k = n^{d+1} - \sum_{i=1}^{n}i^d = 2^4 - 9 = 7 = (111)_2 \tag{2}\label{eq2B}$$

Thus, $l = 3$ and $n_l = n_3 = 1$. However,

$$n - \left\lceil\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d}\right\rceil = 2 - \left\lceil\frac{9}{2^3}\right\rceil = 2 - 2 = 0 \neq n_l = n_3 = 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This fails because $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d} \gt 1$, so the ceiling result is always $\ge 2$, meaning the final result is always $\le n - 2$, but this gives $0$ for $n = 2$. However, your conjecture does work by changing the restriction to be $n \ge 3$.

---

Note that to prove your conjecture, it's sufficient to prove

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^d \le n^{d+1} - n^d \; \iff \; \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^d \le n^{d+1} - 2n^d \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

The left inequality with $d = 1$ gives $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \le n^2 - n \iff n + 1 \le 2(n - 1) \iff 3 \le n$, so it holds.

Next, consider the remaining cases of $d \ge 2$ with $n \ge 3$. Note that $i^d = \int_{i}^{i+1}i^d dx$. Since $\lfloor x \rfloor = i$ for $x \in [i, i + 1)$, we also have $i^d = \int_{i}^{i+1}(\lfloor x \rfloor)^d dx$. In addition, since for non-integral $x$ means that $\lfloor x \rfloor \lt x$, we have $\int_{i}^{i+1}(\lfloor x \rfloor)^d dx \lt \int_{i}^{i+1}x^d dx$. Using these results and summing over the various values of $i$ gives

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^d = \int_{1}^{n}(\lfloor x \rfloor)^d dx \lt \int_{1}^{n}x^d dx = \left. \frac{x^{d+1}}{d+1} \right|_{1}^{n} = \frac{n^{d+1} - 1}{d+1} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

To prove the right side of \eqref{eq4A}, it's sufficient to prove

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{n^{d+1} - 1}{d+1} & \le n^{d+1} - 2n^d \\
n^{d+1} - 1 & \le (d + 1)n^{d+1} - 2(d + 1)n^d \\
-1 & \le dn^{d+1} - 2(d + 1)n^d \\
-1 & \le n^d(dn - 2d - 2) \\
-1 & \le n^d(d(n-2) - 2)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Since $d \ge 2$ and $n \ge 3$ means $d(n-2) - 2 \ge 0$, the inequality above holds, so \eqref{eq4A} also holds. This means \eqref{eq4A} is true for all $d \ge 1$ and $n \ge 3$. Note this gives $-\sum_{i=1}^n i^d \ge - n^{d+1} + n^d \; \to \; n^{d+1} - \sum_{i=1}^n i^d \ge n^d$. Thus, $n^d \le k \lt n^{d+1}$ so, expressed in base $n$, we have $l = d + 1$ and

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
n_l & = \left\lfloor \frac{k}{n^d} \right\rfloor \\
& = \left\lfloor \frac{n^{d+1} - \sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d} \right\rfloor \\
& = \left\lfloor n - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d} \right\rfloor \\
& = n + \left\lfloor -\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d} \right\rfloor \\
& = n - \left\lceil \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d} \right\rceil
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

For going to the last step, note if $x$ is any integer then $\lfloor -x \rfloor = -x = -\lceil x \rceil$, while if $x$ is non-integral so $x = m + r$ with $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \lt r \lt 1$, then $\lfloor -x \rfloor = \lfloor -m - r \rfloor = -m - 1 = -(m + 1) = -\lceil x \rceil$. Thus, for all real $x$, we have $\lfloor -x \rfloor = -\lceil x \rceil$.

Comment: thank you for your solution. my apologize for late reply. I am trying to understand your answer very well. I will respond you in one day. I'm little trouble with bottom part of solution.

Comment: Ok which formula is correct (7) or (8) for $n_{l}$ at what conditions. Please explain again.

Comment: @Pruthviraj You're welcome for the solution & no worries about it taking some time. As for equations (7) and (8), I apologize for my mistake with (7). I got the ceiling & floor functions mixed around. They're now the same, with them applying for all the stated conditions. With (7), the largest coefficient would be the numeric value truncated down (i.e., the floor function) of the power there. On the RHS, subtracting a value in the floor function is equivalent to subtracting the ceiling function normally (I can add a proof for that in the solution if you wish). I hope this explanation helps.

Comment: Now it's most probably clear to me...

Comment: @Pruthviraj I'm sorry but, since I don't have appropriate bounds on the term's coefficients, my answer using Faulhaber's formula for providing an upper limit was not robust (but my statement that your conjecture works for all $n \ge 3$ has not changed). Instead, I'm now using a Riemann integral upper bound in my answer. Please let me know if there's anything unclear about my new method.