# Formula for the $j$th base-$n$ digit of $n^{d+1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^d$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $k,n,d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>1$.

Converting $k$ in a base $n$,

$$k = (n_{ l} ~ n_{l-1} ~\cdots~ n_j ~\cdots~ n_2~ n_1)_{n} \quad\text{where}\quad n_{l} \ne 0$$

> if
>   $$k = n^{d+1} - \sum_{i=1}^n i^d$$ then
>   how to find general formula  $n_j$ for $l> j \geq 1$?

John Omielan well proved formula for $n_l$  with $n>2$
$$
n_l=n - \left\lceil\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^d}{n^d}\right\rceil
$$

[Proof for $n_l$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3316007/647719)

**Example**

Let $n=5$ and $d=4$.

$$k=5^5-(1^4+2^4+3^4+4^4+5^4)$$

$$= 979 = (32041)_{5}$$

So $n_l = 3,n_2=4$.

You can refer following links for better understanding structure

1) [digits pattern of k](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3332250/647719)

2)[progression of first digit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3300245/647719)